# Android: I tried AWS Kinesis video streaming but getting exception?

Tags: android, amazon-s3, amazon-kinesis, kinesis-stream

I tried AWS Kinesis, and I am able to create stream but when I try to put stream in this file I am getting an exception "Exception thrown on sending thread: Exception while sending encoded chunk in MKV stream!"

Please help me to proceed with streaming.

Steps:
1- Implement kinesisVideoCredentialsProvider.
2- get KinesisVideoClientConfiguration.
3- Initialize KinesisVideoAndroidServiceClient.
4- KinesisVideoAndroidServiceClient.createStream.
5- get getDataEndpoint.
6- KinesisVideoAndroidServiceClient.putMedia.

steps 1 to 5 working fine. and stream created successfully
but after that i got "Exception thrown on sending thread: Exception while sending encoded chunk in MKV stream!"

Answer (score 0):

Check out KVS Producer SDK assets on GitHub. Those do exactly what you need. There is a C, C++, Java and Android versions currently supported.